# WebPack & Vue.js proxy to VM not working

Tags: proxy, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-resource

So I am developping a site with vue.js localy on my mac with the webpack-dev-server using `Vue CLI`. I would like to use `Vue Resource` to get the data from my back-end that is hosted on a vagant VM (local.dev). I tried to add a proxy in my config/index.js file like so:

```
proxyTable: {
  '/pf': {
    target: 'local.dev/portfolioVue/public',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/pf': ''
    }
  }
},
```

Then I added this function on mounted in src/App.vue

```
mounted () {
this.$http.get('/pf').then(response => {
  console.log('tutu');
}, response => {
  console.log('erreur');
})
```

}

In src/main.js I added:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'local.dev/portfolioVue/public';
Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = 'GET';
```

This was found on https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/cors-and-vuejs?page=1

But now I am getting these errors

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method"


XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://local.dev/portfolioVue/public/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am symply trying to get a php file (public/index.php) that returns Json

```
<?php echo json_encode('tutu') ?>
```

> Can it be a probleme on the VM config ?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Shouldn't the correct property name be `proxy` instead of `proxyTable`? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy I would highly suggest take a config example and copy pasting one over to see is something actually happens. Names like these `pfVue_2.0` are also never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But now i am getting this error



```XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://local.dev/portfolioVue/public/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have no idea how i can get the acces to work...

Comment: This is a CORS issue. Basically you are not allowed to make XHR requests from one domain to another by default. I am not familiar with the proxy property of Webpack but I am guessing that it can be fixed by tweaking your config. This might be a good start: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxying-local-virtual-hosts perhaps update your question to show what config you have tried.

Comment: Just updated the questions
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

So after researche and this was a CORS probleme and infact there is a plug-in for google chrome that passes over that probleme, ther also are plugins for firefox depending on preference.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi